# Why is printing a C array showing non-contiguous addresses?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

I read that Array bucket values are stored in contiguous memory locations.   I was trying to print a character array's memory location on my `64 bit mac` as

```
char str1[] = "Hell";
    printf("%p:%lu:%c, %p:%lu:%c, %p:%lu:%c, %p:%lu:%c", str1[0], str1[0], str1[0], str1[1], str1[1], str1[1], str1[2], str1[2], str1[2], str1[3], str1[3], str1[3]);
```

and the result I got was

```
0x48:72:H, 0x65:101:e, 0x7fff0000006c:140733193388140:l, 0x7fff0000006c:108:l
```

This doesn't looks like a contiguous memory addresses to me, considering the size of a `char` is `1 byte`. Please help me understand this if I am learning it wrong.

Comment: You don't print any memory address in the posted code.

Comment: Thank you @axiac, I realised my mistake of not putting the `address of ` operator. If you could write it as an answer, I will accept it. Tested with `&` and it is working.

Comment: Crank up the warning level, many compilers will warn you about the mismatch between format-string and arguments.

Comment: I had a question about that @Deduplicator. Although the c compiler throws warning of the mismatched types, is there any harm in printing a 64 bit pointer address with a `%lu` or a `%lx` format specifier on a `64` bit architecture?

Comment: `str1[0]` is a `char`, not an address. You meant `(void*)&str1[0]`. And get rid of `%lu`. It's UB to print an address like that.

Comment: @pkill Yes. It's all undefined behavior, especially in the ... pack of variadic functions where there can be no implicit conversions. All of it needs explicit casts.

Comment: Thank you @PSkocik. Out of curiosity, would you be kind enough to explain how representing a `64 bit` value, in this case a `64 bit pointer`, as a `long unsigned` will cause an undefined behaviour, as the value will fit well within the size of the format specifier on a 64 bit machine? Please forgive my ignorance.

Comment: @pkill Printing a long with `"%c"`` (assuming ints are 32 bit large) is actually dangerous. Printing a 64 bit pointer as a 64 bit unsigned shouldn't be, but you've still given the compiler permission to go bonkers.  Read some of those "what every programmer should know about UB" articles.

Comment: Thank you kind fellow programmers, Thank you @PSkocik.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The arguments in your `printf` statement are incorrect.

If you meant to print the addresses in decimal, here is what you should write:

```
char str1[] = "Hell";
printf("%p:%lu:%c, %p:%lu:%c, %p:%lu:%c, %p:%lu:%c\n",
       (void*)&str1[0], (unsigned long)&str1[0], str1[0],
       (void*)&str1[1], (unsigned long)&str1[1], str1[1],
       (void*)&str1[2], (unsigned long)&str1[2], str1[2],
       (void*)&str1[3], (unsigned long)&str1[3], str1[3]);
```

Note however that converting a pointer to an `unsigned long` might loose information as the size of `unsigned long` might be smaller than that of a `char*` (it is on Windows 64-bit);

If you meant to output the characters in decimal and as characters, the format should be `%d` and the code changed to:

```
char str1[] = "Hell";
printf("%p:%d:%c, %p:%d:%c, %p:%d:%c, %p:%d:%c\n",
       (void*)&str1[0], str1[0], str1[0],
       (void*)&str1[1], str1[1], str1[1],
       (void*)&str1[2], str1[2], str1[2],
       (void*)&str1[3], str1[3], str1[3]);
```